# How to append data to default laravel view after application creation

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an app. I need to add a slider from the `App\Slider` class to the default app layout view. Which is the most efficient way to do this without having to change my controller logic for each controller?

Is there a way I can add the class and function to the `Controller`, `BaseController`, `Service Inject` an instance of the `App\Slider`or use and create a `ViewComposer`. Currently I am stuck on which way would be most efficient as technically I only need to add a foreach loop to the `layouts.app`.

The controller method is already built.

Comment: Can you please add some sample code that highlights the issue you are having?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction! :)

Comment: there is several ways to achieve this, you can initialize the slider into a middleware, or in a service provider, and use view::share to share the slider variable, like so all your blade templates can access it. 
I hope this is what you need, if not, please share some of your code with us as suggested by @Matthew